# How do I post an arraylist with header using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I tried Retrofit for posting array list with header which I added on interface but still getting failed status from server.

This is my request json

```
    {
  "products": [
      {
          "id": "2",
          "quantity": "1",
          "price": "34",
          "name": "product-1"
      },
      {
          "id": "41",
          "quantity": "2",
          "price": "36",
          "name": "product-2"
      }
  ]
}
```

this is the response json

```
    {
    "status": "Success",
    "msg": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "34",
            "name": "product-1"
        },
        {
            "id": "41",
            "quantity": "2",
            "price": "36",
            "name": "product-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

interface

```
    @POST("myliee/api/addOrder")

    Call<Payment_Repo> paynow( @Header("user_id") String userid, @Header("vendor_id") String

 vendorid,@Header("category_id") String categoryid,@Body List<CartModel> members);
```

cartmodel

```
public class CartModel {

    int _id;
    @SerializedName("name")

    @Expose
    String _name;
    @SerializedName("price")

    @Expose
    String price;
    @SerializedName("quantity")

    @Expose
    String tottalcount;
    @SerializedName("id")

    @Expose
    String productid;

    public CartModel() {
    }

    public CartModel(int _id, String _name, String price, String tottalcount,String productid) {
        this._id = _id;
        this._name = _name;
        this.price = price;
        this.tottalcount = tottalcount;
        this.productid = productid;
    }

    public CartModel(String _name, String price, String tottalcount,String productid) {
        this._name = _name;
        this.price = price;
        this.tottalcount = tottalcount;
        this.productid = productid;
    }

    public String getProductid() {
        return productid;
    }

    public void setProductid(String productid) {It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
        this.productid = productid;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_name() {
        return _name;
    }

    public void set_name(String _name) {
        this._name = _name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTottalcount() {
        return tottalcount;
    }

    public void setTottalcount(String tottalcount) {
        this.tottalcount = tottalcount;
    }
}
```

This is my mainactivity where I had called the api

```
     DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(Checkout.this);

        List<CartModel> contacts = db.getAllCarts();

        RetrofitInterface jsonpost = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetrofitInterface.class, 

"http://myliee.com/");

        Call<Payment_Repo> call = jsonpost.paynow(userid,vendorid,categoryid,contacts);

        Log.d("check", userid + ": next :" + vendorid + " " + categoryid);

        // 27: next :1
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Payment_Repo>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Payment_Repo> call, Response<Payment_Repo> response) {

                String statuss = response.body().getStatus();

                Toast.makeText(Checkout.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.d("sss", "Messgase :"+statuss);

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    String msg = response.body().getMessage();

                    List<Payment_data> status = response.body().getData();

                    for (int i=0 ;i<status.size();i++){

                        Log.d("data", "name "+status.get(i).getName()+ "  "+"price 

"+status.get(i).getPrice()+ "  "+"total "+status.get(i).getQuantity());


                    }

                    Toast.makeText(Checkout.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(Checkout.this);

                    db.deleteAll();

                    Intent success = new Intent(Checkout.this, PaymentSuccess.class);

                    startActivity(success);

                    finish();

                } else {

                    Log.d("sss", ": next :" + response.errorBody());

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    Intent fail = new Intent(Checkout.this, PaymentFail.class);

                    startActivity(fail);

                    finish();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Payment_Repo> call, Throwable t) {


                Log.d("sss", "Messgase :"+t.getMessage());


                progressDialog.dismiss();


                Intent fail = new Intent(Checkout.this, PaymentFail.class);


                startActivity(fail);


                finish();


            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change to put headers

like this:

```
void paynow(
    @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
    @Body List<CartModel> members
): Observable<JsonObject>
```

Comment: You can read refer:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: sir, i don't have an issue with header, actually i am confuse how i can post an product array in server.